# Angular Typeahead results shows undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have been learning Angular and tried to implement it in a mock up.When I tried to implement Angular typeahead ,the results of typeahead is shown as undefined can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?
The code snippet of html,

```
 <input type="text" id="search" ng-model = "selectedEnterprise" class="form-control form-design input-md enable collapse" placeholder="search for an enterprise" uib-typeahead = "enterprise.name as vm.enterprises.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3 ">
```

The controller code snippet

```js
 $http.get(path + '/enterprise/all/' + num)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        vm.enterprises = response.data;
                        temp = vm.enterprises;
                        console.log(vm.enterprises);
                    }, function error(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

I use MongoDB and NodeJS framework for Backend.

Comment: Instead of  "enterprise.name as vm.enterprises.name" it should be "name as enterprise.name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your typeahead code

From

```
<input type="text" id="search" ng-model = "selectedEnterprise" class="form-control form-design input-md enable collapse" placeholder="search for an enterprise" uib-typeahead = "enterprise.name as vm.enterprises.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3 ">
```

To

```
<input type="text" id="search" ng-model = "selectedEnterprise" class="form-control form-design input-md enable collapse" placeholder="search for an enterprise" uib-typeahead = "enterprise.name as enterprise.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3 ">
```

In the typeahead,we are creating an reference object enterprise for vm.enterprises(data source) and from that reference object we are extracting name variable and asking it to assign the same to `ng-model`

```
uib-typeahead = "enterprise.name as enterprise.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises
```

Comment: Sorry for using old thread but can we have multiselect functionality on uib-typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
uib-typeahead = "enterprise.name as vm.enterprises.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3
```

Expression should be like

```
uib-typeahead = "name as enterprise.name for enterprise in vm.enterprises | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3
```

You should refer to particular instance `enterprise.name` rather than all the instances `vm.enterprises.name`